# Помогите правильно составить регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно в сообщениях из чата искать примерно такие слова:

```
"JavaScript", "MetallicRagnarokнУидАльшелюбойтекстилицифры3".
```

т.е. буква верхнего регистра, минимум 1 буква нижнего, еще буква верхнего и минимум одна нижнего и еще в этом слове не должен присутствовать символ **"@"**.
Пример:

```
Scottybot Most Recent Code: BestDoggoEver
```

Из примера `true` должно быть только у слова `BestDoggoEver`.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[A-ZА-Я][a-zа-я]+([A-ZА-Я][a-zа-я]+)+
```

[Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/qhdyiV/2)

Вариант, отсеивающий слова, с собакой спереди и сзади слова:

```
(\s|^)([A-ZА-Я][a-zа-я]+([A-ZА-Я][a-zа-я]+)+)($|\s)
```

Правда будет недостаток, в выражение полезут пробельные символы, но можно взять из выражения 2 группу.

[Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/qhdyiV/5)

Наличие символа границы слова, в вашем диалекте, конечно облегчит вам жизнь ;).

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Только даже у "@BestDoggoEver" совпадение, а мне нужно чтобы если есть "@" перед этим словом - не было совпадения.

Comment: @AminIsaev, это будет зависеть от диалекта, как будут определятся границы слова, но один из вариантов, я вам привел.